# Anything to do about "bad" migrations?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55443/how-do-i-repair-a-broken-cable-in-a-retractable-handle-suitcase?noredirect=1#comment112786_55443) (which I think is clear and demonstrates effort in the question formulation) was moderator-migrated away from a community where it seemed to fit and was related to multiple explicit tags, TO a community where it is *not* on-topic as described on [that community's page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I've seen other examples of questions where somebody on site A suggests migration to site B and then I see that a duplicate of that question was originally posted on site B and migrated to A.
Is there a place where questionable migrations can be discussed?

Comment: Isn't it still the case that migrations need to be accepted by a moderator of the target site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, on the meta site of the specific site the post was migrated away from.

This is something you need to discuss with the moderator and the Travel community, so post on https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The OP now asked there: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/migration-to-diy